# Node.js listen to events on dynamically created objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

I have a Node.JS application which dynamically creates Record objects from info stored in a db, each instance of Record emits events, and I'd like to listen to them all.
It goes like this :

```
db.getRecords(function(group){
    for (var i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
        var record = new Record(JSON.parse(group[i].list),group[i].id,group[i].time);
        record.setup();
        record.on('dropped',function(){
            db.deleteRecord(record.id);
        });
    }
});
```

The code above will always listen to the events emitted by the last object created... It makes sense but I can't figure out how to listen to all my Record objects, and react to the evants they emit. Anhy help/suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code *is* listening to the events generated by all your records. However, `db.deleteRecord` will be called, in *all* cases, with the id of the last record covered by your loop. To take a specific instance, the event handler for the first record will call `db.deleteRecord` with the id of the last record.

To fix this, you could do:

```
record.on('dropped',function(id){
    db.deleteRecord(id);
}.bind(undefined, record.id));
```

This will force the `id` passed to your callback to be set to the value that `record.id` has *at the time bind is called*. (The first argument to `bind` sets `this` to `undefined` inside the anonymous function.)